# Disallowing Login from Connected Apps

Tags: connected-apps

I have two connected apps in my developer org. One is for Android and other for iOS devices.
What I want to know is why a user can have multiple login sessions in different devices (or same). Is there a way to not allow a user to login? For example in a Android device and then in a iOS device via connected app?

Another question. Everytime I login on my device app, SF always shows me the permissions page to Allow / Deny the app. Why does this happen? Is it because I didn't publish my connected app yet?

Answer (score 3):

In answer to your first question - you can control access to connected apps via profiles and permission sets. Go to ***Your Name* | Manage Apps | Connected Apps** and click on an app. From here you can change **Permitted Users** to **Admin-approved Users**, and add a permission set to each app. Now you can add users to the relevant permission set.

Salesforce shows the permissions page when you request OAuth authorization ([user-agent flow](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com#Obtaining_an_Access_Token_in_a_Native_Application_.28User-Agent_Flow.29)). Your app should request a refresh token and save that (securely!) on the device. When your app starts it should check for the presence of a refresh token and use the [token refresh flow](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com#Token_Refresh) to obtain a new access token, rather than the user-agent flow.

Answer (score 0):

1. Given user can be logged from up to 4 sources (browsers/apps) at same time, so I don't see any easy way to block user for logging from 2 apps at same time.
2. Are you storing access token in apps? Remember that to be able to obtain token you need access code (which actually is short lived token).